# Checking if geopoint is in shapefile containing world cities

Tags: python, gdal, shapely, reverse-geocoding, pyshp

I have approximately 13 million (lat,long) geocoordinates. I also have a shapefile containing 3460 cities.

I need to find the City in which this geocoordinate can be found.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
from shapely.geometry import shape,mapping, Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon
import shapefile

with shapefile.Reader(r"shapefile-name") as sf:
        point = Point(x,y) 
        for shapeRec in sf:
            polygonalRegion = shape(shapeRec.shape.__geo_interface__)
            if polygonalRegion.contains(point):
                countryCityRegion = [shapeRec.record[2],shapeRec.record[3],shapeRec.record[4]] 
                return countryCityRegion
```

For every unique geopoint I am executing the above process. I then store the result so I don't have to search for the same geopoint more than once.

The issue is that it's incredibly slow. I am unfamiliar with how this process works so I'm completely lost on how to make it faster, if even possible. The shapefile is around 600 mb.

Comment: Try geopandas Spatial join

Comment: Search points from polygons (with an index, it's much faster, though you have to handle "outside" and "in many" correctly).

Answer (score 1):

The data structure people generally use to solve this is an [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), I believe. Shapely has one available ([`shapely.strtree.STRtree`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#str-packed-r-tree)). You could also look at the [`rtree`](https://rtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I've never used it myself but I would guess that the easiest solution here is the one mentioned by @BERA, the [spatial join](https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins) in geopands. You can cut out the `shapefile` dependency to boot and just use `geopandas` to read the shapefile into a `GeoDataFrame` object with columns for all the records in the features.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what @Jeremiah and @BERA mentioned. You can achieve this using both R-Tree and Spatial Join. Spatial join approach is similar to R-Tree because it allows you to quickly find the polygons that are likely to contain the given point, without having to check every polygon in the shapefile. Below is how you can implement it:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
gdf = gpd.read_file(r"shapefile-name")
point = Point(x, y)

match = gpd.sjoin(gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[point]), gdf, how="inner", op="contains") 
ccr = [match["country"].iloc[0], match["city"].iloc[0], match["region"].iloc[0]] # This extracts country, city, and region
```